# Cmake's FindOpenSSL's behavior changed between 3.12 and 3.19 -- and I can't seem to tell Cmake where I want it to find OpenSSL [Windows]

Tags: c++, cmake, openssl

In CMake 3.12, FindOpenSSL() located my locally built version of openSSL for the project in question. In CMake 3.19, FindOpenSSL() generates a search list that finds my locally build version of openSSL AND a version installed on my system that I don't want it to use.

The CMake docs, in their "hint" section, says to set "Set OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR to the root directory of an OpenSSL installation."

I've tried two different mechanisms:

-DOPENSSL_ROOT_DIR=$ENV{MY_OPEN_SSL_BUILD}

and in my CmakeLists.txt

```
IF (WIN32)
        set(OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR $ENV{MY_OPEN_SSL_BUILD}) 
ENDIF (WIN32)
```

Both of which still has FindOpenSSL() creating a search path that includes an openSSL installed on my system, but not the one I built. Although the one I built IS in the search path.

Is there a construct that forces FindOpenSSL() to choose the specific one I want?

@Tsyvarev I made some edits (I should have said this originally, mea culpa).

-DOPENSSL_ROOT_DIR=c:/wrk/builds/release/lib

But either -D option or the explicit setting in my CMakeLists.txt still gets me the following:

In 3.12 -- I get back the following cmake output:

```
-- Found OpenSSL: C:/wrk/builds/release/lib/libeay32.lib (found version "1.0.2x")
```

In 3.19 -- I get back the following cmake output:

```
-- Found OpenSSL: optimized;C:/wrk/builds/release/lib/libeay32.lib;debug;C:/Program Files/OpenSSL-Win64/lib/VC/libcrypto64MDd.lib (found version "1.0.2y")
```

The problem comes into play when linking. The error comes into play because `ASN1_STRING_get0_data` is found in `libcrypto64MDd.lib` which is installed on my system:

```
-- Looking for ASN1_STRING_get0_data in optimized;C:/wrk/builds/develop-VS2019/lib/libeay32.lib;debug;C:/Program Files/OpenSSL-Win64/lib/VC/libcrypto64MDd.lib - found
```

While in my OpenSSL build, which I ultimately link against does not have it.

I hope this clarifies.

Comment: Your locally build OpenSSL seems to be incorrect, no applink found, and cmake found applink in the system OpenSSL. You should fix your build.

Comment: "In CMake 3.19, FindOpenSSL() generates a search list that finds my locally build version of openSSL AND a version installed on my system" - Do you mean that CMake finds some **file** which belongs to your local installation and some **file** which belongs to the system installation? Which **exact** files? Please, be more **concrete** when describe the problem.  Show your **exact** `find_package(OpenSSL)` call, show the **exact search list** which is generated by CMake, and so on.

Comment: Passing option to `cmake` as `-DOPENSSL_ROOT_DIR=$ENV{MY_OPEN_SSL_BUILD}` is **wrong**: construction `$ENV{}` works only inside CMake script. Using `set(OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR $ENV{MY_OPEN_SSL_BUILD})` is incorrect too: it assignes **backslash**-separated path, stored in `MY_OPEN_SSL_BUILD` **environment** variable, to CMake variable `OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR`, which should contain **slash**-separated path. Instead, use `file(TO_CMAKE_PATH "$ENV{MY_OPEN_SSL_BUILD}" OPENSSL_ROOT_DIR)`.

Comment: I instrumented the cmake collateral that comes with Visual Studio 2019 -- and what appears to happen is that while my release build is found, it also picks up the system installed DEBUG version and overrides my release build.

Comment: To summaries: Your custom installation of OpenSSL doesn't have debug libraries, and because of that the module `FindOpenSSL` picks system libraries as debug ones. This shouldn't harm your build unless it is debug build... but probably your build is actually a debug one. The simplest way for resolving the problem would be installing release libraries too. E.g. if you have built your OpenSSL from sources, aside from `cmake --build <...> --config Release --target install` do `cmake --build <...> --config Debug --target install`.

Comment: If you cannot install debug libraries, and you use Visual Studio for build your project, then I fear you cannot do debug builds: As far as I know, with Visual Studio release and debug libraries are not interchangeable. So, the only OpenSSL library you could link your project with is a OpenSSL debug library. Would debug and release libraries be interchangeable, you could substitute release libraries instead of debug. For that, in CMake cache modify value of the variable `LIB_EAY_DEBUG` to be the same as the variable `LIB_EAY_RELEASE`. After that you need to reconfigure the project.